# gretl で latex 出力が出来ない

Tags: latex

gretl での回帰分析の結果を latex 形式で出力しようとしたができない。menu の latex が、グレーアウトして、latex 形式で出力できません。解決方法を教えてください。

Comment: @user12399423　Rとは関係ありません

Comment: OSやインストールしているTeXディストリビューションの種類, インストールしたTeXにPATHが通っているかの確認はどうなっているのでしょうか? (グレーアウトして選択できない, ということだとそもそも正常にインストールできていないのかもしれません)

Comment: @user12399423    web上のgretl使い方解説ではグレイアウトしている図をみますが、よくあるケースと思います。